# Need to write spiral from # and

Tags: c, spiral

I have to create spiral from `#` and `.`. It has to expand according to variable `n`. Problem is I couldn't create it anyhow I try. My program so far gets Segmentation fault on test. In description image is output for `n = 7`.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

```
char a[100][100];
int n = 7;
int r,s;

void write(char *a[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<n;j++)
      a[i][j]=".";
  }
}

void right (int length)
{
  int k=0;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    a[r][s+k] = '#';
}

void down(int length)
{
  int k=0;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    a[r][s+k] = '#';
}

void up(int length)
{
  int k=0;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    a[r][s+k] = '#';
}

void left(int length)
{
  int k=0;
  for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    a[r][s+k] = '#';
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are assigning a string to a char array here a[i][j]="."; You need to assign a char like so a[i][j]='.';

Comment: You ignore the return value of scanf() at your own risk. Consider not to,

Comment: Why are the `up`, `down`, `left`, `right` functions all the same?

Comment: Check your assignment. This assignment is usually created by teachers with the restriction NOT to use and array and instead just print the lines directly in one go.

Comment: @Yunnosch what do you mean by that?  interjay I know, just did ctrl c and ctrl v , ill change them but later on I need to fix segmentation fault first. Thanks for noting me tho

Comment: I do not know how to put it differently... Read the assignment carefully again. I expect it to somehow restrict you from using an array which you first fill and then print. That is usually how these "make a spiral" homeworks go, because they are designed to make you use loops and simple math creatively and to get you out of the "follow the spiral" way of thinking and put you on the more efficient track of "how to make the lines".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about the segmentation fault:

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to change `"."` from string to a char like so `'.'`.

Next is that in your write function, the argument requires the wrong kind of array. You are specifying `char *a[]` when instead you need `char a[100][100]`. This worked for me.

Regarding the intended behaviour, it is up to you what you define a spiral to be.

Comment: Global variables are initialized to 0.

Comment: Did not help, still getting segmentation fault

Comment: @interjay my bad, I've overlooked that

Comment: @Dudo updated the answer

Comment: Works good, thanks. But doesn´t print out anything. If i want to print result out I should use 2 for cycles to print entire array right?

Comment: @Dudo similar to your write function but instead put a print in the inner loop and a new line in the outter loop

Comment: Got it to printf ..... but can´t seem to get it doing #... also will r and s ever change? because they are probably 0 all the time aren´t they? When i call them in those 4 functions (up,down,left,right)

Comment: @Dudo r and s never change in your program. As I said, it is up to you what you define a spiral to be.

Comment: Okay, that was all I needed. Thanks for your kind help ill try to rebuild it :)

Comment: @Dudo on a side note, are you sure you selected the correct answer as accepted?

Answer (score -1):

Your program will be Segmentation fault in write() function whenever you will access array. So that you need to copy entire array in the write () function.  Kindly use below.
write(*a[100][100],int n)

Comment: It doesn't make sense what you trying to do in the write function signature/call